# hmacSHA1 Encryption Question

Tags: apex, encryption

Does anyone know whether the crypto.generateMAC function generates a hmacSHA1 encrypted in binary or hexidecimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a binary blob. If you need it in another form, using EncodingUtil (convertToHex or base64Encode, whichever you prefer).

Comment: You had me for a second. I had to write some code to test it :p